# Dash plotly customized map

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, plotly-dash

I went through various tutorial on mapbox but i am not able to create a sample report of a region in india.i am completely new to css so i am finding it difficult to edit the file from tutorial and put the data from my custom file.
I created a geojson file and downloaded a sample date but i am unable to create a map.
Need some help in creating a regional map file along with some data and interactions.
you can find the json files and a code attached to it in the below link 
https://github.com/9192gks/mapbox

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `Folium` to produce maps in dash, itegrate them via an iFrame. Here are two links to get you started.

[Folium and Dash](https://medium.com/@shachiakyaagba_41915/integrating-folium-with-dash-5338604e7c56)
[Choropleth Maps](https://towardsdatascience.com/choropleth-maps-with-folium-1a5b8bcdd392)